# Nullable Array Notation

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable-reference-types

I am new to nullable.

Is there a meaningful difference between the possible notations?
`string?[] str`
`string[]? str`
and even `string?[]? str` seems to all be valid

Comment: `string?[]` -- an array of strings, where each element may be null, but the array itself may not. `string[]?` -- each element may not be null, but the array itself can be null. `string?[]?` -- each element may be null, and the array itself can be null as well

Comment: `?` allows `null`. `string?[]` - array of string which can have `null` items, `string[]?` array which can be null, but (when it's not null) can't have `null` items. `string?[]?` can have `null` items and can be `null` itself

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When we put `?` after [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) we allow the instance to be `null`. So we have

- `string?[]` - string array where we allow the items to be `null` (but array itself can't be `null`)
- `string[]?` - string array which can be `null` itself (but it can't have `null` items)
- `string?[]?` - both array and its items allowed to be `null`

Comment: Pre C#8 it is always `string?[]?`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: yes, in pre c# 8 we can always assign `null` to item or to array itself; so, technically we have `string?[]?`

Comment: Great answer.  Some confusion might remain though, I hope this doesn't add to it...  Both `Array` and `string` are reference types (which can be null), so `string?` and `string` are equivalent, and `[]` and `[]?` are equivalent (and there is no difference between `string?[]?` and `string[]`) in "vanilla" C# regardless of version. For the distinction to be made, nullable reference types as a feature has to be explicitly activated `#nullable enable` because it is an otherwise breaking change to the language which makes such conventionally equivalent statements non-equivalent.